# All optional parameters but one must be passed

Tags: python

I am writing a class method that retrieves the player on a team. A player object has two unique attributes: `account_id`, `account_name`. The simplified class structure looks like this:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, account_name: str, account_id: str):
        self.account_name = account_name
        self.account_id = account_id

class Team:
    def __init__(self, players: List[Player]):
        self.players = players
```

(The team class has more than just a list of players as an attribute, I excluded them for simplicity)

I want to write a function `Team.get_player()` that has two optional parameters (`account_id` and `account_name`). I want the user of this function to be able to pass one or the other since you can find a player using either of them.

THE QUESTION:
Does it make sense to have a function (similar to below) where there are two optional parameters, but the function requires that you pass one. Should I just divide the function into `get_player_by_name`, and `get_player_by_account_id`? I like the idea of having one function to do both but I'm unsure of the best way to do it or if it should even be done at all...

```
    def get_player(account_name: str = None,
                   account_id: str = None) -> Player:
        passed_args = locals()
        if not all(passed_args[key] is None for key in passed_args):
            raise TypeError('Team.get_player() takes 1 positional argument but 0 were given')
        if account_name:
            ...
        if account_id:
            ...
```

Comment: They're also not supposed to pass both arguments, right?

Comment: How about `def get_player(key: str, value: str)` where `key` is either `'name'` or `'id'`?

Comment: since both paths are likely to share a lot of code, I might make an internal `get_player()` and a pair of veneer methods `get_player_by_name()` and `get_player_by_account_id()` that simply called `get_player()` as appropriate.

Comment: @Barmar well you could pass both and in my example account_name would be used...

Comment: Presumably, `get_player_from_name()` is the composition of a hypothetical `get_id_from_name` and `get_player_from_id` functions. (Or `get_player_from_id` is the composition of `get_name_from_id` and `get_player_from_name`.)

Comment: How about *def get_player(**kwargs)* then require your user to pass a named parameter - e.g. *get_player(name='Franco')* or *get_player(account=42)*. In that way, *get_player()* can find out what it's been passed and know how to deal with it

Comment: Presumably, `id` is unique to a player, while `name` could be shared by multiple players. `get_player_from_name` could conceivably return *multiple* players, which lends weight to the approach of implementing `get_players_from_name` in terms of `get_player_from_id`.

Comment: @DarkKnight doesn't that seem unnecessary considering that there are only two potential arguments?

Comment: @chepner both name and id are unique

Comment: Of course, if the name and id can be uniquely identified by their type or value then you only need one parameter

Comment: @DarkKnight ah I see, I figured it would be overkill to implement **kwargs, at that point, I may as well use the get_player in the question. In both cases I will have to have the if statements to check what was passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither argument is optional on its own, but the use of one prohibits the use of the other: they are mutually exclusive.

It's cleaner to provide two separate functions, each of which has one *required* argument and is implemented in terms of a lower-level private method.

```
NameOrID = Union[Literal['account_name'], Literal['account_id']]


class Team:
    def __init__(self, players: List[Player]):
        self.players = players

    def get_player_by_name(self, name: str):
        return self._get_player('account_name', name)

    def get_player_by_id(self, id: str):
        return self._get_player('account_id', id)

    def _get_player(self, attr: NameOrId, val: str):
        for p in self.players:
            if getattr(p, attr) == val:
                return p
```

If you really want, you can make `_get_player` public, but it's not clear you need that kind of flexibility in your public API.

Comment: `_get_player()` might be overkill, but it does improve encapsulation.

Comment: @JonSG Yeah, I caught one copy-and-paste error, but not that one.

Comment: I would not say they are mutually exclusive. There is no reason that passing one means that you cannot pass the other. They are both unique identifiers and as such, if both are passed it does not matter which one is used to perform the look up. In any case, I will consider implementing it as two separate functions..  I wanted  one simple function that handles all the logic though :(

Comment: What is the function supposed to return if you provide two values that select two different players? If you don't have a good answer to that question, then parameters effectively exclude each other, even if Python syntax and semantics can't express the mutual exclusion.

Comment: That is a good point, in that case it would break. But is it really up to me as the creator of the library to account for the possibility that you pass an account_id of one player and the account_name of another? In that case, I could return either Player and in both cases my function would have done what it was supposed to do...

Comment: You think your caller won't care which `Player` gets returned? They may have made a mistake by passing identifiers for two different players, but you're *enabling* that mistake by making your function behave non-deterministically (the caller can't predict which player will actually be returned) rather than treating it isn an error. Having two different methods (or even the private method that requires a "tagged" argument) prevents that error from being made.